# Condicional ? en PHP

Tags: php

En una prueba de un entrevista de trabajo me preguntaron cual es el valor de $var en esta expresión:
$var = true ? '1' : false ? '2' : '3';
Se que if y else puede sustituirse por "?" ":" y también he podido comprobar en un sandbox que el resultado es "2" pero no termino de entender la condición, cuando entraría en cada caso, que hace exactamente esa expresión. ¿podéis echarme un cable a entenderla paso a paso?

Gracias!!

Comment: Busca "Operador ternario".

Answer (score 3):

Vamos a descomponer la expresión:

```
true ? '1' : false ? '2' : '3';
```

Esto, por precedencia de operadores es equivalente a:

```
((true ? '1' : false) ? '2' : '3');
```

Evaluamos la primera expresión:

```
(true ? '1' : false)
```

Como el primer operando es verdadero (true), la expresión devuelve el valor antes de los dos puntos, es decir `'1'`.

Ahora tenemos la siguiente expresión:

```
'1' ? '2' : '3'
```

Para evaluar si '1' es verdadero o falso tenemos que saber si '1' es truthy o falsy.

¿Cómo se sabe si un valor es falsy y se evaluará como negativo?:

Un valor es falsy si:

- Es el boolean FALSE
- Es un entero 0
- Es un float 0.0
- Es una cadena vacía
- Es la cadena '0'
- Es un array con cero elementos
- Es un objeto con cero variables miembro (En PHP4)
- El tipo especial NULL
- Es un objeto SimpleXML creado con etiquetas vacías.

En caso de que no sea ninguno de esos valores, es un valor truthy y se evalúa como true.

Por lo que '1' no es ninguno de la lista, y pasa a ser true al evaluar, por lo que se devuelve otra vez el primer elemento antes de los dos puntos, es decir '2'

Me he basado en esta respuesta para los truthy/falsy:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382490/how-does-true-false-work-in-php